How to use WordPress REST API to login a user with dart/flutter?
I'm creating an app that will work on phones, tablets and computers. I need to be able to authenticate a user, reset a password, retrieve their name and email, all via the WP API.
I have zero clue how to do this and I'm trying to read the docs but I don't understand them.
This would be my first time doing something like this.
I know how to do this on the flutter/dart side. I'm specifically looking to see what the endpoint would be and if I need to use cookies or if 1 user creating an app password would work.
